# Grafana + Prometheus: Query to display the highest of three values in singlestat panel

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I am trying to find a way to write a query in grafana which will display only the highest of three values (coming from kube.state.metrics / prometheus) in a singlestat panel.

I have tried using max(), but this only returns the highest value of a timeline of a single metric.

I am looking to get the following output:
Variables: a = 10, b = 15 , c = 4
Query: maxValue(a, b, c)
Result: 15

Is this possible in Grafana / PromQL?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution.
I am using a plugin, called "Blendstat" for Grafana, which is basically a singlestat panel with added support for more than one query.

In the visualisation tab is a "blend mode" parameter, which lets me choose "Max". The result is the highest value of the three queries.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking vectors (as in "a sample with labels"), then this should work:

```
(metric1 > metric2 or metric2) > metric3 or metric3
```

If you're talking scalars, then you'd need to add a `vector()` around each value.

Comment: Hi Alin, I tried your suggestion, but it didn't work.
However, I have found a solution by myself now.